# How do you verify that the device time is correct and someone is not tampering with the device time. I want to implement this for both android and ios

Tags: javascript, android, ios, firebase, react-native

I did a little research on this and these are the thoughts I came up with.

1. Implementing a custom logic to check whether the device time is correct or not(I'm using firebase for backend).
2. Checking whether the device's **Automatic date & time update** is set to true(If not set forcing the user to set it).

I believe the second option makes more sense to implement for this issue.
Need react native implementation or some guidance on how I can implement this(I'm using react native version 0.62.2).
Also if you have any other way around to tackle this issue, please suggest.
Thank you.

Comment: The Realtime Database has a special data location at the path [`.info/serverTimeOffset`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-latency) that should return the difference between local device time and server time. I'm unsure of how frequently this is updated, but investigating further could lead to it being a suitable time manipulation indicator.

Comment: I'm not an android expert, but if you need time to be synced, you have to use server time instead of local time. there, using some tools like ntp, you can assure your time is synced.

Comment: You cannot trust device time.  Use a trusted network server, either via NTP or your own server.

Answer (score 0):

To verify the correct device time you need to check device time with server time. Firebase Cloud Firestore provides the current UTC timestamp. You can use the device milliseconds and Firestore timestamp milliseconds to verify the time

Reference for React-Native Firestore: https://rnfirebase.io/reference/firestore/timestamp